# Is it possible to drag a TPanel to outside the TForm?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm wondering if it's possible to make something like this:

[image]

but without creating a second TForm.

I'm using Delphi 7, but if a newer version make it possible just tell me.

Comment: Investigate the VCL's docking support. There should be a demo included in your copy of Delphi.

Comment: Have you looked at DockEx.Dpr in the Docking folder below Delphi's Demos one?

Comment: I've seen the dockex.dpr, although I need to create another TForm, I think it will work for me. Thank you both.

Comment: The VCL's docking system creates its own TForm for you if you drag a dockable control off of its parent container and don't drop it onto another container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always thought the DockEx demo was over-complicated for learning the basics of docking.

The following is the simplest example I know of:

- Add a TPanel to a blank form and set its DragKind property to dkDock, DragMode to dmAutomatic and its Align property to alTop.
- Drop a TButton on the TPanel
- Add the code below to the form:
- Run the project and manually drag the panel off the form.
- Click Button1.

The above shows how Delphi can undock a Panel (or TEdit, etc) without you
needing to create a second form to host it while undocked, like Remy said in a comment.  The Button1 click-handler shows a way (admittedly imperfect) of re-docking the panel.  Next:

- Undock the panel again, but this time, click the Close button on its auto-created host.

Then, read the OLH and figure out a) how to get the now-hidden panel visible again and b) to re-position & re-align it on the form as it was prior to undocking,

```
  type
    TMyClass = TControl;

  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    TMyClass(Panel1).ManualDock(Self, Nil, alNone);
  end;
```

Comment: The panels `DragMode` must also be set to `dmAutomatic`

Comment: Are you sure about the default value? The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.DragMode) tells a different story